# Using a FK as the descriminator in an inheritance mapping

Tags: entity-framework-4

Consider the following schema: Employee, and EmployeeType. Employee has a fk to EmployeeType (EmployeeType might have fields like EmployeeTypeId, Description, etc...).

Now I would like to use EF's inheritance feature to create objects HourlyEmployee, and SaleriedEmployee based on the Employees fk field.

This does not seem possible. Every avenue I have tried has failed. Since Employee's FK is the descriminator for the mapping to the derived entities HourlyEmployee and SaleriedEmployee and the FK to the table EmployeeType.

Is there anything I can do short of adding a seprate field in Employee that is an duplicate of the fk field?

Comment: If you don't map relation and EmployeeType table you should be able to handle FK as any other column and use it as discriminator. If you map the relation the inheritance is redundant and you cannot use FK as discriminator because it is already used to handle relation and each column can be mapped only once.

Comment: How is the inheritance redundant?

Comment: Because if you map relation your inheritance doesn't make sense. The information is already part of relation. What is worse relation can be changed and your employee can change the type. That cannot happen with inheritance. Once you create HourlyEmployee instance you will never change it to SalariedEmployee without creating new record in the database or changing discriminator directly through SQL.